# mvn is not recognized after installation Maven 3

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have some problems with my maven 3 installation.

I have downloaded maven 3.0.3 and extracted it to a folder.
I set the following environment variables.

- M2_HOME:
   `C:\a few folders\apache-maven-3.0.3`
- M2:
   `%M2_HOME%\bin`
- JAVA_HOME:
   `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25`
- Path:
   `%JAVA_HOME%\bin; %M2%`

I get a message that the command is not recognized when i type "mvn" in the command line. Any ideas?

Comment: what does mvn --version says ?

Comment: exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156647/installing-maven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything looks OK.

- I don't know if there should be a space after the semicolon and `%M2%`. This might be your problem.
- Make sure you typed a "a few folders" correctly.

Comment: I knew it had to be something stupid. It was the space indeed. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: You have got to be kidding me. I had the exact same problem, and my error was also the space, although on the PATH-variable...

Answer (score 4):

Maven 3.0.3 and later doesn't need the `M2_HOME` variable.
The following environment variable changes are sufficient to run Maven from the command-line:

1. Setting `JAVA_HOME` to the Java `jdk` directory (eg. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29`)
2. Setting `PATH` to include the Maven `bin` directory.

Comment: Downside of that is that you will reach the maximum value of the environment variable faster. I'd rather use shortcuts so you can fit more in the path environment. Also using shortcuts makes it a lot more readable.

Comment: Also this wouldn't have solved my issue (years ago) since the problem was the actual space. Not the way variables where set up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add(create) these new variables at the SYSTEM VARIABLES (M3_HOME and M3):

```
 M3_HOME: C:\maven_installation_folder\

 M3: %M3_HOME%\bin
```

Include at: "CLASSPATH" and "Path" variables

```
 CLASSPATH: other_variables;%M3%;

 Path: other_variables;%M3%;
```

Go to Command Prompt (cmd) and type:

```
 mvn -version
```

Answer (score 0):

Maven 3.0.3 and later doesn't need the M2_HOME variable. So no need to add that.

I did the following in the Windows System variables and it works:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31
Path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin;C:\Selenium 3\Maven\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin
```

Comment: Downside of that is that you will reach the maximum value of the environment variable faster. I'd rather use shortcuts so you can fit more in the path environment. Also using shortcuts makes it a lot more readable.