# Installing Maven

Tags: maven, installation, environment-variables

I am having trouble getting Maven 3.0.3 to install properly. I have read over [Unable to install Maven on Windows: "JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184056/unable-to-install-maven) but none of the answers were able to solve my problem.

This is what I did:

- Went to http://maven.apache.org/download.html and downloaded apache-maven-3.0.3-bin.zip
- Extracted files to C:\Program Files, so I now have a directory called apache-maven-3.0.3
- Went to my system's environment variables and created user variable `M2_HOME`, value is `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin`
- `JAVA_HOME` variable is set properly, can get version from cmd line
- Edited `PATH` so the value is now `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;%JAVA_HOME%;%M2_HOME%`

When I go to cmd, I this is what I get:

```
   D:\>java -version
    java version "1.6.0_25"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)

    D:\>mvn --version
    'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
```

However, if I am actually in the directory I can do the following:

```
D:\>cd C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin

D:\>C:

C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin>mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 11:31:09-0600)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.3
Java version: 1.6.0_25, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Is this how it should actually work? From what I have been told I should not have to be in the directory like that to use any mvn commands. Thank you for your time!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven 3 installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755137/maven-3-installation)

Comment: You're missing an enviroment variable `M2`.

Comment: your `M2_HOME` should be `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.3`. And I doubt the fact that you're able to print the java version is coming from your `PATH` variable, as you're supposed to set it to `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`.

Comment: Same problem, but the solution that worked for him does not work for me

Comment: Changed so I have M2 = %M2_HOME%\bin, M2_HOME = C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.3, Path = %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;%M2%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin. Still having the same problem, unfortunately

Comment: @A D, the final part is wrong. `PATH` should be having `M2`

Comment: was a typo sorry - edited my comment to reflect proper Path

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just keep these two things in mind :

- Any filesystem path containing
  whitespaces in between should be
  surrounded with double quotes. e.g. `set M2_HOME="C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.3"`
- `PATH` should contain the directory
  in which your executable exists. If `M2_HOME` is your `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.3`, the `PATH` should be `%M2_HOME%\bin`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did what you said but move the variable to be a system variable instead of user variable and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

One very simple issue I had is that in Windows you need to close and then reopen CMD after every change to your variables.

Comment: you might want to phrase your answer better, so it would be self-contained.

Comment: yes, in Windows, all changes to environment variables require a restart of the CMD line environment.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem on my 64bit win7 machine and finally fixed when I add another **user variable** with the name **Path** and content with `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2%`. You have **Path** in System variables but also add in user variable as I described.

Answer (score -1):

http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/windows-prerequisites.html

> Maven is written in Java (and primarily used to build Java programs).
>   Thus, the major prerequisite is the Java SDK. You need to install the
>   Java SDK 
>   Oracle's download site, **and you should install it to a pathname
>   without spaces**, such as c:\j2se1.6.

It worked when I changed the location to some other without spaces than `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.3`. But on the other computer the location with spaces worked without any troubles.

edited:
I meant that on official website, exactly here in Windows' tab, point 2: http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

> 2.Add the M2_HOME environment variable by opening up the system properties (WinKey + Pause), selecting the "Advanced" tab, and the "Environment Variables" button,then adding the M2_HOME variable in the user variables with the value C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.2.

It is not emphasized to avoid spaces, even they are used in example. I found it confusing so I had a need to write it here. I didn't say a word about Java SDK.