# the system does not recognise maven

Tags: java, maven

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156647/installing-maven)

I have set all the environmental variables as follows, but when I enter mvn --version the system does not recognize the commend, the unzip downloaded source code of maven is located in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.4

User variables

```
 M2        %M2_HOME%\bin
 M2_HOME   C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.4
 PATH      %M2%
 JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11
```

System variable

```
  JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11
  PATH      
  %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Apps Sync\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Apps Migration\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11
```

Comment: Have you try to call use mvn.bat instead? Try to echo all env variable and make sure all variables pointing to intended value. E.g: echo %M2%, echo %PATH%, etc. Also check whether you have mvn.bat inside %M2%

Comment: For Windows (DOS) to execute a command, it looks through its path variable to find a .bat, .com, or .exe file with the name of the command.  You say the maven stuff is loaded under Apache Software Foundation under Program Files, but I don't see that anywhere in the PATH variable.  The PATH needs to have in it the directory where windows can find the 'mvn' bat, com, or exe file.  (I think there are tricks one can do with the registry that also make a command active, but this seems the most likely cause.)

Answer (score 0):

(Haven't tested or verified, just a possible direction you may look into)

afaik, Windows' environment variable settings in System Properties is evaluated in order of the key name.

Therefore , M2 is evaluated before M2_HOME is set with value.  As a result, M2 is set with `\bin` and hence, PATH is not correctly set.

To verify, please open command prompt, type `set M2` and `set path`, and you should see the value set.

Easiest way to solve is to do these only:

```
set M2_HOME=your_manve_path
set PATH=%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;whatever;other;path
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

System Variable

```
M2_HOME   C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.4   
JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11
PATH      
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Apps Sync\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Apps Migration\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```